# Dell Latitude 5490 Intel GPU 3 monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, displayport, usb-c

I have 1xusb-c (DP supported), 1xhdmi and 1xVGA output from my laptop.

I can connect usb-c to monitor A, HDMI to monitor B but I want to connect also monitor C.

I have a hub which has usb-c and HDMI input to usb-c out. I try 1xHDMI in directly to laptop, 1xHDMI  in  to hub and 1 usb-c (dp) in to hub then I connect hub to my laptop over usb-c (dp). But it does not work.

Above scheme what do I do wrong or how can I get 3 monitors display for my laptop.

Note: I disable laptop's built-in screen.

Comment: Are you sure the hub has **inputs**? That would be a first... Apart from that the graphics may not support that many monitors.

Comment: See https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000131612/how-to-configure-three-3-displays-on-a-dell-latitude-notebook-with-intel-hd-4x00-graphics You need to ascertain exactly which GPU you have.

Comment: @ChanganAuto What do you mean? Hub has 1 hdmi and 1 usb-c input and it outputs usb-c.

Comment: @Tetsujin uhd 620 system Ports - 3 displays max with LCD plus 1 display max on each output (HDMI, VGA (14 inches/15 inches) Docked - 3 displays max (combo of LCD, VGA, DP, HDMI)

Comment: Yes, but the HDMI port is an output.

Comment: I am talking from the hub side, that is why I wrote like that